# Any way to make cross server ajax calls?

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

I am learning XML and I've found a website that has a XML feed. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to make cross server ajax calls?

The code I am using is below:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        // Interpret response
        $(xml).find('g').each(function() {

            // Example: Show the XML tag in the console
            console.log(this);

            // Example: Put some output in the DOM
            $("#divOutput").append($(this).attr("hnn"));

        });

        $(xml).find('g').each(function() {



            // Example: Put some output in the DOM
            $("#divOutput").append($(this).attr("k"));

        })        

    }
});
</script>

<div id="divOutput"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Sorry I don't share more details, but I'm not familiar enough with it to help. Worth reading about, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only ways for you to make cross domain ajax requests (that I'm aware of) are:

1. Use [JSONP](http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/)
2. Use a proxy

   - A related alternative to this might be to use the [Google Feed API](https://code.google.com/apis/feed/) (or similar service)
3. If the server supports it (and you'll usually need to control the server), use [access control headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control)

In this case, it looks like you can't do any of these, so you're out of luck.