# Getting the text out of a different webpage through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, windows-desktop-gadgets

First of all hello everybody,

I'm new to this site but I still searched for 10 minutes and couldn't find an answer to my question so I'll ask it now.

I'm trying to create a sidebar gadget for windows vista/7.
In that gadget I need to get some text from another page in the web (not in my domain).
I know I can't really do it but I've found a work around with an Iframe.
Right now the page I want is loading through the Iframe and I can see that.

The question is how do I get the entire text of that page in the Iframe into a label or text area or whatever...

Since the windows sidebar gadgets doesn't work with ASP I need this done with pure HTML and javascript.

Anyone that can help me please do,
Thanks,
Sagi.

Comment: AJAX + CORS will solve your problem, but only if the site you are requesting from allows it.

Comment: AFAIK, for Sidebar Gadgets there are no SOP-like restrictions. Just use an Ajax request to get the resource that you need. Or do you develop a Web Gadget?

Comment: I'm developing a sidebar gadget.
if you can give me a guide or the code on how to take the text from lets say: www.bbc.com I could take it on from there.
Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar may not allow ASP, but it will certainly allow ajax calls, your asp page will reside on the server and do all this hard work, and your gadget will just call your asp page?

Comment: ok I get it now... but as a matter of fact I don't have any server to preform this on, isn't there any other option to work locally without any use of any server or any asp pages?

Comment: OK, I thought you would have some server at least, since you mentioned ASP. Anyhow, for cross-domain ajax restriction issue this might help, though I haven't tried this myself in particular but i think YUI can help, http://jpvalappil.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/cross-domain-ajax-the-yui-way/ , there are other similar ones available out there too

Comment: Also try, YQL http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/ or http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Comment: thank you for these links but I already looked at these examples and they didn't help me (or I didn't get them and that's why they didn't help me...)
thanks anyways.

Comment: Is there a proxy issue? Are you able to load remote js scripts?

Comment: I don't think I can.
And again since I'm new to this thing I don't know if there is a proxy issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to do an ajax call to the server where the other webpage is hosted.
jQuery might help with this (using `.ajax()`), otherwise, just google how to do this normally in js.

**[EDIT]**
An intermediate server/proxy where you do the ajax calls might help, you can use access control headers to allox cross-site-scripting.  See my [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035169/any-way-to-make-cross-server-ajax-calls) for more info :)

Comment: I can't use ajax since the page I'm loading to the Iframe isn't mine. that's why I asked in the first place.
I saw this option but dismissed it right away since the page isn't on my server.

Comment: I looked at this answer and it's not giving me what I want...
I just need the text from let's say www.bbc.com

If you could write some code example on how to do it that I copy paste to my html file I'll get all the necessary adjustments on my own.
If not well then I guess I'll have to drop that one.

I pretty new to jquery and I only heard JSON one time before so this is a new zone too.

Thank you very much for trying to help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the fact that the page escapes your Iframe is the issue you can set up an intermediate server, that gets the text from the server you want (as you mentioned; www.bbc.com), and serves it as clean text.  Have your widget then include an ifram from the text from you intermediate server.  This would be the cleanest approach really.

Comment: Ok so how do I that?
Do you have any guide for me to try?